# SSL error while installing syslog-py using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, ssl, syslog

Trying to install `sylog-py`:

```
pip install syslog-py --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --proxy="http://<xxxxxxxxx>:<xxxxxxxxx>@<0.0.0.0>:<xxxx>"
```

But received this error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/syslog-py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/syslog-py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/syslog-py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/syslog-py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/syslog-py/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/syslog-py/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/syslog-py/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement syslog-py
ERROR: No matching distribution found for syslog-py
```

Please let me know how to install `syslog-py` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method -

```
python -m pip install syslog-py --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

Successful response -

```
...
Collecting syslog-py
  Downloading syslog_py-0.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.0 kB)
Installing collected packages: syslog-py
Successfully installed syslog-py-0.2.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is the system I am working on is under the Defence organization, India which doesn't allow proxy easily. So I am getting errors. I will try on my personal laptop and update the status. Thank you.